# Unable to create the menu after deleted an old one

Tags: routes

On Drupal 7, I just deleted an old menu(menu A) under "Administration > Structure > menus". When I try to create this same menu "menu A", it said `The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique.` How can I fix this?

Comment: Cleared Caches already?

Comment: @koivo did it few times

Comment: @koivo It's working after I resaving the Views that was using the "menu A".

Comment: Hooray, cool! :D